# Plotting a single line with two different colours with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I'm trying to plot a set of data with `ggplot2`. The data are in two categories. I would like to plot them together, with a single linear regression line. However, I would like to have each of the two groups plotted in different colours. Here's what I get:

[image]

Here's how I got it:

```
library(ggplot2)
dframe1 <- structure(list(a = 1:6, b = c(5, 7, 9, 10.5, 11.7, 17), category = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L
))
qplot(a, b, data = dframe1, colour = category) + geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

How do I make the plot only use one regression line for all the data?

*Note: Quite apart from this, I'm puzzled as to why only one of these lines has confidence intervals shown, but that's not the point of my current question*.

Comment: Regarding your note: For a perfect fit the confidence band has zero width.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just modify the aesthetics to exclude the grouping factor:

```
qplot(a, b, data = dframe1, colour = category) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=NA),method = lm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The equivalent of @Roland's answer, using `ggplot` instead of `qplot`

```
ggplot(dframe1, aes(x = a, y = b)) +
    stat_smooth(method = lm) +
    geom_point(aes(color = category))
```

Comment: (+1) Once you avoid `qplot` and use `ggplot` it's much easier to understand the syntax.

Comment: (+1 again) Agreed. Both of these solutions work. In fact, I'm using yours, but since Roland correctly answered the question first, I'm marking that one as correct.